# gcc: warn if macro was redefined (regardless of previous definition)

Tags: gcc

[gcc's manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Undefining-and-Redefining-Macros.html) says the following:

> If a macro is redefined with a definition that is not effectively the same as the old one, the preprocessor issues a warning and changes the macro to use the new definition. **If the new definition is effectively the same, the redefinition is silently ignored.** This allows, for instance, two different headers to define a common macro. The preprocessor will only complain if the definitions do not match.

(emphasis mine)

Is there a way to make gcc more strict and issue a warning when a macro is redefined, regardless of definition?

Example:

```
#define TEST 1
#define TEST 1

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` does not generate any warning whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Techincally speaking, if a header defines an apple as being red, then another wants to make sure everybody knows the apple is red, this should not be an issue. This is the reason behind it. And also to not compromise linking between multiple libraries if they have the same macro definition and the same value.

- some h/hxx/hpp header

  #define apples red

It's the usual attitude when you see some people wanting to make sure everyone knows they know (we all have these friends or co-workers, don't we? :) ) that apples are red so they state the obvious.

Preprocessor definitions are "compiled" (so-to-speak, rather said, interpreted and replaced or evaluated accordingly) at, well, compile-time. So having the same token defined multiple times is no real overhead on the app, it might just add a bit of compilation time.

The problem is when some wise-guy wants to let you know apples can also be green.

- some *other* h/hxx/hpp header

  #define apples green

Then, when you need to use some apples, you end up with:

- some c/cxx/cpp file

  #include "some_header.h/hxx/hpp"

  #include "some_other_header.h/hxx/hpp"

And you end up with  *"apples " redefined*.

Putting aside the daunting task of seeing where the conflict comes from (usually when combining multiple third-party libs/framerworks that might use similar names in macros or have the same acronyms prefixing a macro), this should be enough for you to know there is a conflict.

Keep in mind, this is a warning, so it will not stop the compilation. To treat warnings as errors, use **-Werror**.

I wouldn't worry about duplicate definitions, to be honest. They won't harm the code. If you really wanna go overkill-mode, you can always do some testing:

```
#if defined(apples) ...
```

... or ...

```
#ifdef apples ...
```

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer. I understand why you might want to tolerate multiple definitions of the same thing, I was just hoping that there would be a way to make gcc more strict in that regard.

Comment: Well, the explanation behind is the reason why it would never be stricter. As I said, when developing large apps, you'll end up with a lot of libs, either in-house made by a different team (or even by you) or third party libs. You might even have to work with that the client has to integrate your app with his system. Imagine that you had one more cpp file to make, you do your #include and everything falls apart when it's 99% done because you had `apples` def-ed twice. I know you mean it to be optional, but there is no point because there is no impact. -Werror will handle the impact :)